# Silverlight: How to get before changed value of textbox when textchange event fired

Tags: silverlight, textbox, textchanged

I have a textbox, when textchange event fired, I want to compare the old value with the changed value.

How to get the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the [KeyDown-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the TextBox. This is event is raised when a Key is pressed and before the [TextChanged-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the TextBox is raised.

In this event, you can get the current Text by calling the Text-Property of the TextBox.

```
TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
myTextBox.KeyDown += KeyDownOnMyTextBox;
myTextBox.TextChanged += TextChangedOnMyTextBox;

string currentText = string.Empty;
string newText = string.Empty;

private void KeyDownOnMyTextBox(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
  currentText = myTextBox.Text;
}

private void TextChangedOnMyTextBox(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e){
  newText = myTextBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: But the KeyDown Event unable to capture the "Backspace", if user delete text, it still go to the textChange Event, and textChange event unable to get the old value.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to make a note of the value each time this event is fired or you assign it a value.

Then you can compare it.